# android facebook api 4.1 - post game achievement

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I would like to post achievements from an android game to the users facebook wall. 
I am using the facebook api 4.1 and after hours of trial and error still running into troubles.

I show a ShareButton in my Layout:

```
 <com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Then I register the onClickListener on the button:

```
  ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
  shareButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The following code is executed, when onClick is performed:

```
 // Create an object
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "game.achievement")
            //.putString("eaustria_net:achievement", "http://samples.ogp.me/161147604019932")
            .putString("og:title", "Hole dir die Frogsmasher app unter: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eaustria.net.findthebug")
            .putInt("game:points", highscore)
            .build();

    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("games.achieves")
            .putObject("achievement", object)
            .build();
    // Create the content
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setAction(action)
            .setPreviewPropertyName("achievement")
            //.setPreviewPropertyName("achieves")
            .build();
    ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "sharedialog onSuccess");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "sharedialog onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "sharedialog exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
    shareDialog.show(content);
```

After clicking on the sharebutton, fb shows up for a very short time and closes again. Log cat says:

> sharedialog exception: Failed to generate preview for user.

I think this correponds with the action-label. Yet I have no idea how to change this. I have created a open-graph action on fb with the following url: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/games.achieves?`

In the manifest.xml I put the app_id:

```
`<string name="facebook_app_id">827293344022992</string>`
```

Any ideas where I am wrong?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also facing the same problem. Please help here.

Comment: no I have not yet solved the problem. But I do not put any more effort on this topic - just using the google play services - this works fine.